# Do Apple Card co-owners get their own titanium Apple Card?

Tags: apple-card

According to [this Apple knowledgeable article](https://support.apple.com/en-al/HT212020), Apple Card participants get their own titanium Apple Card. However, in the same article, it does not say whether or not an Apple Card co-owner gets their own titanium Apple Card.

Do Apple Card co-owners get their own titanium Apple Card?

Comment: Why not ask Apple?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a simple customer service question.

Comment: I've seen other Apple Card questions on this site. Is this question out of scope for this site? If so, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in Apples Article (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212020):

What account owners and co-owners can do on a shared Apple Card:

...

- They can add or remove participants and order a titanium Apple Card for participants who are under 18 years old.

...

Comment: I would add that this is basically the point of adding someone to a card–so that they can make purchases with the card.

Comment: So ordering a card for participants is also ordering a card for a co-owner? They are clear these two entities are distinct in their article. This statement does not make it clear that a co-owner will receive their own card - only that a co-owner can order a card for a participant (which is not a co-owner).

Comment: @SwisherSweet You are correct that the quote picked out here doesn't answer your question - however you are reading into the difference between participants and co-owners a bit too much: they're the same except for financial liability on the card.

Comment: @SwisherSweet I suspect you won't find an actual answer for the reason I mentioned in my first comment: it's implied that somebody who's added as a spender on the card get's a card to spend with.